# how to set vertical align of uitextview from interface builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, uitextview

I have a problem in my application design. I want to set vertical align middle of my UITextView.
Please help me how to set vertical align of uitextview from interface builder.

Comment: what do you mean by vertical align.Do you wnat that your text in text field should come in center.

Comment: I want to show my text in middle of textview

Comment: And also there is a padding in uitextview, I want to remove it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got this to work by observing changes to the contentSize property and then setting contentOffset.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [myTextView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:nil];
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    UITextView *myView = object;

    CGFloat offSet = ([myView bounds].size.height - [myView contentSize].height * [myView zoomScale])/2.0;
    offSet = offSet < 0.0 ? 0.0 : offSet;
    [myView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -offSet) animated:NO]; 
}
```

Comment: This works well for iOS 6, but doesn't seem to work for iOS 5. The UITextView seems to behave differently. :(

Comment: working well on ios8 but also needs to remove observer after alignment is done. Add this line as last line of `observeValueForKeyPath` method: `[tv removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize"];`

Answer (score -1):

```
*yourtextviewname*.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

You can do this by interface builder.Open attributes of text field and set text Alignment to center.

Comment: Sorry that is not mean of mine, I am using UITextView and want to set vertical align e.g top,middle,bottom. 

Hope this make sense.